# python nested reverse loop

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a reverse loop nested with a for loop, once the for loop meets a certain criterion then the reverse loop kicks in to obtain the required information I'm searching for based off of a second, consistent, criterion that I know. Normally one would do the for loop to look for the required information; however, I only know the criterions and I don't know the required information other than it's listed prior to the criterions and can be in one of three different formats. I'm using Python 3.6.

EDIT: It looks like what's throwing me off is the different formatting of 'what I'm looking for'. To simplify it lets just go with 1 specific format, the information I want can be grouped with information I don't want.

```
searchList = [['apple'], ['a criterion for'], 
['what Im looking for'], ['a criterion for what Im looking for   not what Im looking for'], 
['fish'], ['coffee'], ['oil']]
saveInformation = []
for n in range(len(searchList)):
    if 'coffee' in searchList[n]:
        for x in range(n, 0, -1):
            if 'a criterion for' in searchList[x]:
                 #this part just takes out the stuff I don't want
                 saveInformation.append(searchList[x])
                 break
            else: 
                 # the reason for x+1 here is that if the above if statement is not met, 
                 #then the information I am looking for is in the next row. 
                 #For example indices 1 and 2 would cause this statement to execute if index 
                 #3 was not there
                 saveInformation.append(searchList[x+1])
                 break
```

Expected output

```
saveInforation = ['what Im looking for']
```

Instead the output I'm getting is

```
saveInforation = ['oil']
```

Comment: Please can you double check your code and output? The first code snippet you show does indeed give a list containing `['what Im looking for']`, which doesn't match the output you say you're getting.

Comment: Both versions give me `['what Im looking for']`.

Comment: Well, your code does gives the required output! That is 'what Im looking for', instead of coffee. You should print saveInformation and check for the same.

Comment: That's a mouthful to answer and I can't answer it concisely other than from what I see with the data I have it's the easiest way. The required information I need to find can be formatted 3 different ways (that I've seen so far), the criterions I know because those were given to me. The file has the information I'm looking for listed anywhere above the criterions (either the next line up, or 30 lines up). So, I loop through the criterions to see if they're met within the data, if a criterion is met then I back up looking for the required information that I actually want.

Comment: Looks like I simplified the code too much then, I'll try to edit the question to recreate the problem.

Comment: I was able to edit it and recreate the problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better not to nest the for loops, but instead split up the problem in distinct steps. It's probably even best to make a separate function for each step.

Your requirements are not entirely clear to me, but I think this does what you need:

```
def search_forward(searchList, key):
    for i, element in enumerate(searchList):
        if key in element:
            return i
    raise ValueError

def search_backward(searchList, key, start):
    for i in range(start - 1, -1, -1):
        if key in searchList[i]:
            return i
    raise ValueError

searchList = [['apple'], ['a criterion for'], 
['what Im looking for'], ['a criterion for what Im looking for   not what Im looking for'], 
['fish'], ['coffee'], ['oil']]

coffee_index = search_forward(searchList, 'coffee')
a_criterion_for_index = search_backward(searchList, 'a criterion for', coffee_index - 1)
saveInformation = searchList[a_criterion_for_index + 1]
print(saveInformation)
```

Comment: With some tweaking I can make this work, thanks! At the very least it gives me the right information when I use saveInformation = searchList[a_criterion_for_index] for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question yesterday, so i will give you the code and explain how you could implement it.

> First you need a list which you already have, great! Let's call it `wordlist`. Now you need a code to look for it

```
for numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
    if wordlist[numbers][0] == 'the string im looking for':
        print(wordlist[numbers])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small list comprehension to achieve a similar effect:

```
search = ['apple', 'im looking for', 'coffee', 'fish']
results = [item for item in search
           if 'coffee' in search
           and item == 'im looking for']
```

This will perform the checks you need, only adding the item that you want into the new list, and even then, only if your criterion item is present.

You could even add more items to search for like so:'

```
itemsWanted = ['im looking for', 'fish']
```

Then in your list comprehension replace `if item == 'im looking for'` with `if item in itemsWanted`

As a side note, you can reduce the number of checks performed by doing the if statement right at the start:

```
if 'coffee' in search: # criterion matched
    results = [i for i in search
               if i in itemsWanted]
```